# Google Code or SourceForge for smaller XCode, Objective-C project?

Tags: svn, xcode, google-code, sourceforge

Which would be a more appropriate repository to host a small, XCode, Objective-C based project? Both appear to offer SVN, which XCode likes. The documentation and issue tracking systems would surely accommodate a small project. A Google search surfaces a number of opinions preferring Google Code, but the motivations seem to be somewhat 2006-ish.

Are you hosting or participating in a project hosted on either platform? Which would you recommend and why? Thanks!

Comment: I eventually chose google code. It works well so far, and svn integration with xcode works well enough for my needs. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using SF for a few years and now I am switching to Google Code. I like Google's bug tracker (which now has API!), I like code reviews feature, server-side cloning of Mercurial projects. And Google Code is just fast. I don't like that SF becomes slower and slower and its UI becomes more and more strange. Search on SF trackers and forums sucks too.

Answer (score 1):

XCode's svn support is sketchy at best, so I would not necessarily give svn bonus points for this.

I use [Unfuddle](http://www.unfuddle.com), which does have svn support, issue tracking, release planning and supports multiple projects.

I happen to use git as my source control format, which also works with Unfuddle, but that was really only becasue I wanted to learn to use git.

Comment: Most people I know that use anything at all, use git.

Answer (score 0):

I have just signed on to XP-Dev for free SVN hosting. It's all closed too, which I can't say the same for google code (can anyone verify if they let you have it closed?). Similar to other posts, the built in SVN support is a pain. That said, I use it, but I did have to redo the server a number of times because of build folders getting checked in and other stuff.